# Setting both onClickListener and onTouchListener to a View

Tags: android, listener, gesture

I need to set both an onClickListener and an onTouchListener to a View. When setting only one of them the corresponding listener works as expected, but when I set both, only the touch listener is called, i.e. gesture works, but click doesn't...

Anybody can help?

```
verticalSwipeDetector = new GestureDetector(new VerticalSwipeListener());
verticalSwipeListener = new View.OnTouchListener() 
{
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (verticalSwipeDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) 
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
};


gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        // never called
    }           


});

gallery.setOnTouchListener(verticalSwipeListener);
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue by any chance?

Comment: what is the difference between a click and a touch that happens at some set place without any associated motion? Could you put the code that needs to run when you "click" in the onTouchListener and check for a touch that looks like a click?